# Correction to the residue in QED using $\overline{MS}$ contains IR divergence

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

I'm Calculating the next-to-leading orders in QED, but I'm using $\overline{MS}$ scheme, as known in $\overline{MS}$ the residue is no longer one and I have to calculate the correction to the residue from the electron self energy, and then multiply the LSZ formula by $R^{1/2}$, but I have found an IR divergence in the correction to the residue, and when I collected all next- to leading orders in the cross section the IR divergence from the vertex correction is cancelled with that from the soft Bremsstrahlung. But the IR divergence from the correction of $R$ when we multiply it by the leading term giving an additional NLO term is still there and I can't cancel it.